# Xamarin - Can't Debug on iPad

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Today I upgraded iOS, MacOS, and Xcode, and now I am unable to debug the .NET Standard / PCL project part of my iOS app. I have a .NET Standard library where all of my non platform specific code held. Then, the iOS project at the highest level contains only the bare minimum iOS specific code.

The setup is like this:

Visual Studio 2017 (15.2 26430)

Xamarin   4.5.0.486 (fec6f88)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.10.0.37 (ad35de4)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xcode 8.3.3

VS 2017 -> MacOS (Xcode - 10.12.6) -> iOS (iPad 10.3.3)

I am pretty sure that we had debugging working at some point, but now it doesn't work. I am running in debug mode in Visual Studio. I switched the Build Time, and Runtime over to use Debug on Xcode. What is odd though, is that I am catching unhandled exceptions in my high level iOS project. Exceptions are bubbling here:

[image]

I have break on all exceptions turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, I fixed on my side changing .Net Runtime Mono 5.0.1.1 to 4.8.1 in the xamarin studio preferences.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... Well, Xamarin Studio doesn't exist anymore from my understanding, but the same thing does exist in Visual Studio for Mac. I found this same thing there.

Comment: I set the default runtime to 4.8.1 but I have a feeling that this did absolutely nothing. I don't really understand the connection between this screen and how the app is built. The whole Mac build system is voodoo. How do we know what processes are going on on the Mac when we do a build? This hasn't fixed my issue.